# Java: Multiple objects of a same java class?

Tags: java

Suppose i have two java classes A and B and if i create the multiple objects of java class B in A. So does it mean that each object is allocated separately in the memory

Comment: Show us some code. Your question is not clear.

Comment: @Matt Ball : Sorry, But i can not add the source here. I jut wanted to ask if multiple objects of same class uses shared or separate memory allocation.

Comment: @sam: you don't have to show *your* code specifically, but rather a generalized example in code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, each object is separately allocated in memory. Whether or not you should use a single instance of class B entirely depends on what you're doing. If you fundamentally need two separate instances with different state, it's hard to see how you could get away without creating two instances...

Answer (score 2):

If multiple instances of class A can function correctly using the *same* instances of class B, then make the instances of B `static` within class A.

eg

```
public class A {
    // Every instance of A has access to this single instance of B
    private static B b = new B();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> So does it mean that each object is allocated separately in the memory

Yes

> Do i have to use single instance of class B to save memory ?

What are you trying to accomplish here?. It totally depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Each object will get its own memory allocated to it so if you have multiple instances of `B` declared inside of `A`, each will be allocated separately.

The general rule of thumb is to create instances as often as you need them. Unless you're creating an insane number of them or you're working in a very constrained hardware environment, there will be no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of a class is separate and uses its own chunk of memory.

You don't need to worry about that at all, unless you're creating millions of instances.

Answer (score 0):

Every object you allocate of a particular class will use a separate memory location.  If you want to save by using shared functionality, you can use the [Flyweight Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).